# HTML Table Formatting Aligning Image in Column 1 With Text in Column 2

Tags: html, pardot

I am working on updating a table in a Pardot email template. I am trying to align an image in column 1 with the first line of text in column 2. Meaning, for this master template, when users go in the first line text will remain in alignment with the image and additional lines of text can be added below in column 2- currently when lines are added the first line of text is bumped up higher in the cell and is no longer in alignment with the image in column 1.

```html
 <tr pardot-repeatable="" style="">
      <td align="center" style="padding:20px 0">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="hund" width="90%">
       <tbody>
        <tr pardot-repeatable="" style="">
         <td align="center" class="rePad" pardot-region="" style="text-align:left; color:#333333; font-family:Calibri,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:21px; padding:20px 0"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="width: 87px; height: 113px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><img alt="" border="0" height="75" src="https://mma.marshmma.com/l/644133/2019-08-28/hslnh/644133/69036/Icons_TrainingsHead_emerald.jpg" style="width: 75px; height: 75px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="75"></span></td>
   <td style="width: 424px; height: 113px;"><span style="text-align:left;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><b>Title</b></span><br>
   Content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="width: 87px; height: 107px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">&nbsp;<img align="left" alt="" border="0" height="75" src="https://mma.marshmma.com/l/644133/2019-08-28/hsmhk/644133/69076/D_I_icons_Committees.jpg" style="width: 75px; height: 75px; float: left; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="75"></span></td>
   <td style="width: 424px; height: 107px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><b>Title</b></span><br>
   <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">Content</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="width: 87px; height: 107px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><img alt="" border="0" height="75" src="https://mma.marshmma.com/l/644133/2019-08-28/hslnf/644133/69034/Icons_handshake_Amethyst.jpg" style="width: 75px; height: 75px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="75"></span></td>
   <td style="width: 424px; height: 107px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><b>Title</b><br>
   Content</span></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think i have a understanding of what you are trying to say, so in order to place text below, there are currently two ways that i see it. either place the text in div tag such as

```
<th>
    <td>
        <img src="https://mma.marshmma.com/l/644133/2019-08-28/hslnh/644133/69036/Icons_TrainingsHead_emerald.jpg" width="50"></td>
    <td>Test Test Title content</td>
</th>
<div>Test im placing text below</div>
```

or another method of placing text below is by using a paragraph tag such as

```
<th>
    <td>
        <img src="https://mma.marshmma.com/l/644133/2019-08-28/hslnh/644133/69036/Icons_TrainingsHead_emerald.jpg" width="50"></td>
    <td>Test Test Title content</td>
</th>

<p> test i have more text below</p>
```

However it looks like the that the Div tag will be more suited to you as i feel like you will be using this code in the navigation bar

Comment: [Please format your code correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)